# Django RegexValidator Not working as expected

Tags: python, regex, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm stuck with the RegexValidator Class.

I'm trying to allow input of some defined HTML(p, ul, li) tags in a Character Field. The following Regex does exactly what I need but I'm having difficulty implementing it.

```
    <\/?(?!p|ul|li)[^/>]*>
```

I'm trying to implment it into my Django model in the following way:

```
     description = models.CharField(max_length = 255, validators=[
                                        RegexValidator(
                                            regex =  r'<\/?(?!p|ul|li)[^/>]*>',
                                            message = 'Disallowed Tags',
                                            code = 'DISALLOWED_TAGS',
                                        ),
                                    ],
                               )
```

I'm using Django 1.6. When I implement the above code, it seems that all form submissions (Using Admin Interface) fail validation.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I think that your regexp is wrong. Try to enter something like `<something>`

Comment: Thanks MoiTux. I have tested this regex on REGEXR and it doesn't seem to be faulty.

Comment: Just to be clear, the above also sees a normal string ex. "Test", as being invalid.

Comment: Yes that normal, you need at lest one '<' and one '>' in that order. I try your code and I'm able to both validate and fail the form.

Comment: if REGEXR doesn’t find a math django won't either thus the validation will fail

Comment: I get what you're saying.Apologies for being a little bit slow. Any idea on how to allow some HTML Elements and throwing a validation message if element is not allowed?

Comment: The following rule seems to almost work :   regex =  r'<(?!/?(p|ul|li)(>|\s))[^<]+?>'. The only problem is that instead of allowing the listed tags, validation fails on only these. It is my understanding that the inverse param has been added to the Regex class in Django 1.7. Any idea how I can achieve something similar in 1.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your own validator and if the regexp matches throw an error since it shouldn't be allowed.
[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/) more info about validator.

```
import re
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def test(val):
    if re.match('<\/?(?!p|ul|li)[^/>]*>', val):
        raise ValidationError('Disallowed Tags')

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 150, validators=[test])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works like a charm on my CharFields & TextFields. Tried using it on TinyMCE editor ( content = tinymce_models.HTMLField(validators=[check_for_invalid_html_tags])), but doesn't seem to have the same result. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: I don't really know TinyMCE editor, but it might encode the HTML entities.

Comment: That does not seem to be it. I've tested it by changing my REGEX to [0-9] and typing in a numeric value. Did not raise a validation message. Anyway, I will keep on testing and update when I find a solution.